# Incoming text activates button

Tags: android, button, view, sms

I have an app that I'm trying to set up so that when I receive a text containing a certain phrase (Currently set to "This is a test" just to test it), a button onClick event will fire.  If my message receiver was in my main activity, I could simply call .performClick().  However, I cant get it to work unless the message receiver is in a seperate class.

MessageReceiver.java

```
package com.defsoftsol.snow.alert;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);    
        Log.i("MessageBody",  messages.getMessageBody());
        if(messages.getMessageBody().contains("This is a test")) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "It worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do a performClick() on a button thats in MainActivity.java?  Can I somehow access the View from that class?

manifest entry

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity.MessageReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Logcat from crash when receive text with receiver in mainactivity.java

```
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.defsoftsol.snow.alert.MainActivity.MessageReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.defsoftsol.snow.alert.MainActivity.MessageReceiver
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2100)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4428)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.defsoftsol.snow.alert.MainActivity.MessageReceiver
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2095)
01-30 20:31:57.002: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: You could use a `LocalBroadcastManager` within your `MessageReceiver`, and register that `LocalBroadcastManager` within your Main class

Comment: Any chance of some sample code?  Im still kind of new to Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make MessageReceiver as a inner class of mainactivity, and then, you can call button.performClick in your mainactivity

```
public class MainAcitivity extends Activity
{
   private Button button;
   ....

   ....

   public static class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
   {
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
      {
           button.performClick();
      }
   }

 }


<receiver android:name=".MainActivity$MessageReceiver" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Do you mean basically if I just copy/pasted the messagereceiver class into mainactivity.java? If so Ive tried that, the app crashes when I receive the text.

Comment: When I do that the app crashes, ill post the logcat in question

Comment: you need declare your receiver as static and in your manifest file use MainActivity$MessageReceiver, $ not .

Answer (score 0):

In your `MessageReceiver` class add

```
private static final String SMS_INTENT = "SMS_RECEIVED"; //you can name this whatever
```

and inside your `onReceive` method add

```
 if(messages.getMessageBody().contains("This is a test"))
 {
     //Toast.makeText(context, "It worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Intent intent = new Intent(SMS_INENT);
     LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);//this sends a local broadcast within your app
 }
```

Then in your `MainActivity` add:

```
private static final String SMS_INTENT = "SMS_RECEIVED"; //you can name this whatever
```

In `onCreate`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(SMS_INTENT));
```

Then create a `Broadcast receiver` class in your `Main`

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do something 
                PerformClick():
      }
};
```

Lastly remember to unregister your receiver in `onDestory` in your `Main`

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Tony Stark's answer simplified it all for me